# Is it possible to access same info as alert in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have access to a private indicator, and I want to use the crossings of the two lines supplied by it. Represented as Line1 and Line2. I can currently set up alerts if these cross, but I cannot seem to be able to do this type of reaction in PineScript.

I want to access a private indicator crossing in PineScript to make a strategy, is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Input From Another Indicator With Your Strategy

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/nm0u5dZi/?solution=43000474048

But you have two lines (Line1 and Line2). I think it works with just one input